# change the authentication route Laravel 5

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

how can I change the authentication route like 'auth/login' to 'career/login' and 'auth/logout' to 'career/logout'? by default it is 'auth/login' and 'auth/logout'

Comment: do you have any code

Comment: if you know laravel, i bet it doesnt need a code, i just need those file names and file location that associates with authentication so that I could change them or modify them by myself

Comment: ok i will look in to it @Code Demon

Answer (score 4):

You simply just need to change your `app/Http/routes.php` and edit the routes for your AuthController.

```
Route::get('/career/login', 'Auth\AuthController@getLogin');
Route::get('/career/logout', 'Auth\AuthController@getLogout');
```

You can also define several properties on your `AuthController.php` to change things such as where the user is redirected after logging in, logging out, etc.

## AuthController.php

```
// Where the user should be redirected after logging in.
protected $redirectPath = '/career';

// Where the user should be redirected after logging out.
protected $redirectAfterLogout = '/career/login';
```

### Update:

If you're changing the login route I would also suggest you change the `app\Http\Middleware\Authenticate.php` middleware to redirect to your new login route when someone isn't authenticated on a protected page.

```
return redirect()->guest('career/login');
```

Comment: Also, I think it should mention that in `app/Http/Middleware/Authenticate.php` (the default authentication middleware), you want to adjust the route there too. Look for this line of code: `return redirect()->guest('auth/login');`

Comment: This answer seems to be outdated for Laravel 5.4

Answer (score 1):

Check out routes.php in the app directory.

Here is an example of one of my development ones:

```
Route::get('/authtest', array('before' => 'auth.basic', function()
{
    return Response::json(array(
        'error'  => false,
        'result' => ''
    ), 200);
}));

// Route group for API versioning
Route::group(array('prefix' => 'api/v1', 'before' => 'auth.basic'), function()
{
    Route::controller('user', 'UserController');
    Route::resource('account', 'AccountController');
    Route::resource('order', 'OrderController');
    Route::resource('appointment', 'AppointmentController');
    Route::resource('invoice', 'InvoiceController');
    Route::resource('item', 'ItemController');
    Route::resource('itemcategory', 'ItemCategory');
});
```